# PHP - round() function with PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN mode (unexpected behavoir)

Tags: php, rounding, floor, ceil

Currently I am working with PHP 5.3.29 and the **round()** function in ***PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN*** mode to round a specific number.

Here is my code:

```
function getBetragrabatt($betrag, $rabatt, $ratezahl = false){
    if(!empty($rabatt)){
        $rabatt = str_replace(array(",", "."), array("", ""), $rabatt);
        if($ratezahl >=1)
            $abschlag = ($rabatt / $ratezahl);
        else
            $abschlag = $rabatt;
        $abschlag = floor($abschlag / 100) . '.' . ($abschlag % 100);
        $rabattbetrag = ($betrag - round($abschlag, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN));
    }
    return $rabattbetrag;
}

$rateRabatt = getBetragrabatt(119.95, 100, 18);

echo $rateRabatt;
```

If I use the code on sandbox ([click here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4af54dccb033b912c310ea4a0b34705cbc62b51b)) everything works as expected and I get ***119.95*** as result.

If I use the same code within my IDE or upload it to my server, I get ***119.40*** as result.

What am I doing wrong?
Hope you can help me..

Comment: This doesn't really fix your problem but you really want to switch to a newer version of PHP where I, dare say, this will be fixed (like in the sandbox).

Comment: @H2ONOCK I would like to do that too, but I am currently dependent on this version :(

Comment: Assuming that PHP version is in fact your issue, you'll need to write your own function that deals with rounding rather than using PHP's native one. Some of the comments on the php website may help... http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: @H2ONOCK I'm using the version 5.3.29 and according to the documentary the round function with PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN mode is available since Version 5.3. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of that but I'm wondering if there was a bug in that version, I can't remember that far back. I'd be interested to hear how you get/got around the issue.

Comment: @H2ONOCK Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution. I am "avoiding" the problem by using the floor function: round (floor ($var)). This approach is, of course, not perfect.